# Which material are piezoelectric buzzers made of?

Tags: materials, reference-request

Which material are these buzzers made of?

[image]

Does it depend on the manufacturer or they all are made of the same material? The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piezoelectric_speaker) does not say anything about the material. I found some [datasheet](http://www.puiaudio.com/pdf/AB2065B-LW100-R.pdf) online but it also does not reveal the material. Is there a reference where I could find more about the properties of this material?

Comment: Usually, they use the so-called (by non-chemists) piezoceramics. A frequently used material of that kind is Lead-Zirconate Titanate

Comment: and used in reverse (force produces voltage) are used to produce a spark as in manual gas lighters.